# Erro system.net.webexception: 0 utilizando a biblioteca IBMWIoTP

Tags: c#, api, biblioteca, syntax-error, ibm

Estou trabalhando com a biblioteca [IBMWIoTP](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-csharp) para fazer um `POST` de um equipamento na plataforma IBM Watson IoT Plataform.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
public void AddDevice(){

    try{

        ApiClient client = new ApiClient("a-i7wplp-paqfsd43pem", "bcO9?&jg9Kb4GOTo)&");

        var device = new RegisterSingleDevicesInfo();
        device.deviceId = "device6";
        device.authToken = "defaultToken";

        Boolean status = client.RegisterDevice("r3000", device);

    }catch(Exception e){
        @Info.Trace("AddDevice -> " + e);
    }

}
```

O erro aparece quando a seguinte linha é executada:

> Boolean status = client.RegisterDevice("r3000", device);

O erro que me retorna é o seguinte:

```
system.net.webexception: 0: em IBMWIoTP.ApiClient.RestHandler(Method methord, String urlSuffix,
    Object param, Boolean parseDynamic, ResRequest customRequest) em IBMWIoTP.ApiClient.RegisterDevice(
    String type, RegisterSingleDevicesInfo info) em DeviceManagementSample.SampleDeviceManagement.Main
    (String[] args) na C:\Users\caiohr\source\repos\teste2\Program.cs: linha 29
```

Não costumo pedir ajuda, mas procurei e pesquisei em vários lugares da internet e não encontrei nada parecido. Procuro a solução ou qualquer informação a respeito, artigos ou livros que possam me ajudar.

Desde já, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido mudando de rede. O proxy da empresa em que trabalho barrava o `POST`, usei uma outra rede disponibilizada pela mesma e consegui fazer o `POST` normalmente.